# JMeter: Capturing JSON (GET) Thread Group-1, modify value and Send in another request (PUT) as a payload (Thread Group-2)

Tags: json, http, jmeter, request

How to JSON (GET) Thread Group-1, modify value and Send in another request (PUT)  as a payload (Thread Group-2), my scenario as below

[image]

Sample JSON response received from Request(GET)

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "**Acronym**": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any pointers is highly appreciated, thank you so much!

Best wishes,
Ashwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

data.glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.Acronym = 'SGML 1234'

vars.put('data', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString())
```

refer generated value as `${data}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)